# How to do search on elasticsearch using java api with a list as parameter

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch

I am trying to run a query in elasticsearch cluster from java api; I have a list of string values and I would like to get all documents which contains any one of those string values. How can I do it? I tried the following but did not work.

```
List<String> tagList = new ArrayList<String>();
tagList.add("grails");
tagList.add("elasticSearch");
tagList.add("java");
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("mongoindex")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
    .setQuery(fieldQuery("tags", tagList))
    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's late but maybe it can help someone else. You can build a `terms query` using `bool query` with `should` clause.

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tags", tagList));
```

After that continue as usual, assuming there exist a field `tags` which holds those values.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("mongoindex")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
    .setQuery(boolQuery)
    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
List<String> tagList = new ArrayList<String>();
tagList.add("grails");
tagList.add("elasticSearch");
tagList.add("java");
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("mongoindex")
.setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tags", tagList))
.setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
.execute()
.actionGet();
```

Check [this link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to see more details about the terms query.

Comment: here, the field 'tags' is not an array, its a simple string field and I want to list all documents which have 'grails', 'elasticsearch' or 'java' in the field; any one of them. thanks

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested in the answer? It looks good given your requirements...just use a terms query (supports multiple values) instead of a field query.

Answer (score 0):

For youre purpose you need to create the query with separate terms so it will search for at least a single match.
Something like this

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
tagList.forEach(tag-> boolQuery.should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("tags", tag));
boolQuery.minimumShouldMatch(1);
```

And then use it in your search.

"minimumShouldMatch" is to be sure that at least on tag is present in a matched document.